# Wrap inside tag XSLT

Tags: xslt, xhtml

How can I wrap content inside tag if it has children like ul or ol using xhtml & xslt? You can look at example to understand what i mean.

Example:

```
   <ul> // Input file
        ...
        <li></li>
        <li>text1 <div>text2</div></li>
        <li>text3 <div>text4</div> text5 </li>
        <li>text6 <ul><li>text7</li></ul> </li>
        <li><div>text8 <ul><li>text9</li></ul></div></li>
        <li>
            ...
            <ol>...</ol>
            ...
        </li>
        ...
    </ul>
```

Output file:

```
    <ul> // Output file
        ...
        <li></li>
        <li>text1 <div>text2</div></li>
        <li>text3 <div>text4</div> text5 </li>
        <li><div>text6 <ul><li>text7</li></ul></div></li>
        <li><div>text8 <ul><li>text9</li></ul></div></li>
        <li><div>
            ...
            <ol>...</ol>
            ...
        </div></li>
        ...
    </ul>
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample input xml snippet if you are using XSLT?

Comment: I see two places where you've wrapped `<div>` around some content, but there are other similar places where you don't. Can you explain the rule for how you know which pieces of content you want to wrap `<div>` around? That would enable someone to advise you on what kind of XSLT templates to use.

Comment: @LarsH if li element has children ul or ol and its contents is not wrapped in div then wrap otherwise just copy content

Comment: @PhilVallone `<?xml-stylesheet href="list.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<html>
  <body>
    <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li>text1 <div>text2</div></li>
        <li>text3 <div>text4</div> text5 </li>
        <li>text6(123) <ul><li>text7</li></ul> </li>
        <li><div>text8 <ul><li>text9</li></ul></div></li>
        <li>(123)
          <ol>
            <li>элемент нумерованного списка</li>
            <li>элемент нумерованного списка</li>
          </ol>
        </li>
      </ul>
  </body>
</html>`

Comment: See David Carlisle Answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**XSL**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="li[ul|ol]">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
         <div>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
         </div>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Produces**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><ul> // Input file
        ...
        <li/>
        <li>text1 <div>text2</div></li>
        <li>text3 <div>text4</div> text5 </li>
        <li><div>text6 <ul><li>text7</li></ul> </div></li>
        <li><div>text8 <ul><li>text9</li></ul></div></li>
        <li><div>
            ...
            <ol>...</ol>
            ...
        </div></li>
        ...
    </ul>
```